# How to calculate array values in XRM?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamics-crm

I have a problem in xrm webapi, my scenario is i need to get all those quotes whose status is won and get their total amount as well, suppose quote a total amount is 1 and quote b has total amount 2 and quote c has total amount 3, it should add totalsum as = 6 but i'm getting error 6[object object].
My code is as follow

```
    function onSaveOpportunity(executionContext)

{
    debugger;
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    var opporId = formContext.data.entity.getId();
    var attrWonQuotes = formContext.getAttribute("dstmda_wonquotestotalamount").getValue();
    Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveMultipleRecords("quote","?$select=totalamount&$filter=(statuscode eq 4 and opportunityid/opportunityid eq "+ opporId +")").then(
    function success(result) 
    {
        debugger;
        var totalAmount;
        for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) 
        {   
            var totalAmount = 0;
            console.log(result.entities[i]);
            var results = result.entities[i];
            totalAmount = results["totalamount"];
            totalAmount=totalAmount+results;
        }
            attrWonQuotes.setValue(totalAmount);
            alert("pass");
                            
        // perform additional operations on retrieved records
    },
    function (error) 
    {
        console.log(error.message);
        // handle error conditions
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem lies here

```
var attrWonQuotes = formContext.getAttribute("dstmda_wonquotestotalamount").getValue();
```

in variable `attrWonQuotes` you are not getting attribute object rather it's value.

```
 attrWonQuotes.setValue(totalAmount);
```

This is not correct rather it should be

```
formContext.getAttribute("dstmda_wonquotestotalamount").setValue(totalAmount);
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: It's not working I'm getting error on console for the line you suggested, the error is as follow: Uncaught (in promise) UciError: Value should be of type: string: Parameter Name: value

Comment: what type of field is dstmda_wonquotestotalamount? from error seems to be string? if it is so you have to change your totalAmount to string